# I can't find my deleted questions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

I was able in past to view my deleted questions by clicking recent deleted questions but I can't now, I need to migrate one to another site.

I knew that I can't see deleted questions past 60 days, I think I should be able to see my own deleted questions no matter how much time past.

Comment: *"after a long time"* - how long? Note that it's **recent** deleted questions, they aren't kept forever (60 days, IIRC).

Comment: @jonrsharpe The questions are kept forever, you just aren't given links to them after a while.  If you kept (or get some other way) a link to the question, it'll still be there.

Comment: @Servy interesting, thanks; I'd assumed that they were deleted (partly because if they're still there, why not show the links?)

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed a feature, questions older than 60 days are not visible in that list.

See this (partially implemented) feature request on MSE: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)