# How long is deleted question stored?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I have a low reputation in stackoverflow and I get this warning `Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more`

Fearing that warning I removed some of my questions which one of them also was put onhold or deleted by moderators.

And now I wonder contents of the questions I deleted. Since I have a low reputation I am unable to see deleted questions. Last week I asked help from a high reputed member, he took a look at my profile but he only noticed only one deleted question by me.
I wonder now what happened to my other question which was `already destined to deletion by moderators`

Did I lose it forever?

Comment: You can see your own recently deleted (60 days?) questions via your profile, but they're never really gone; a moderator can see them.

Comment: You can see your own deleted questions for 60 days: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288101/i-cant-find-my-deleted-questions

Comment: `I removed some of my questions` it would be better to try and fix them up

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Deleted posts are normally stored forever; they are only soft-deleted and still visible to 10k+ users, moderators and the original author.

Any *recent* questions you posted (< 60 days ago) that have since have been deleted can be seen in your *recent deleted questions* view, linked from your question tab. No other users (not even those with 10k or more) can see this list, and the questions are not listed elsewhere.

Moderators *can* see all deleted posts in your profile. You have 4 deleted questions, all older than 60 days, so only a moderator can list these for you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705761/regex-how-to-clean-up-deb-packages
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130578/compilation-error-in-libdesktop-agnostic
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313054/does-terminal-output-to-file-have-an-maximum-limit
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801122/how-can-i-exclude-some-library-paths-listed-in-pkg-config-variable-pc-path-p

Note that deleting posts does not help avoid posting limitations based on quality issues, such as a question ban or rate limit. If you can instead improve the quality of the  questions that would be a better option.

Comment: Just a small clarification for curiosity, if you don't mind : when you say question younger than 60 days, does that mean an older question, deleted today wouldn't appear in that list?

Comment: @Patrice: exactly. The question has to be younger than 60 days; it is the *posting date* that counts here, not the deletion date.

Comment: bit of a counterintuitive behavior, but it's not really worth changing it I assume :P. thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters
Thank you for answer, you helped lots. You said that deleted question stored permanently, it's the same even if I deleted a question that was also deleted by moderators? If I remember correctly one of my question was already put to delete or close.

Comment: @kenn: yes, it doesn't matter who deleted the post.

Comment: @MartijnPieters
Your help much appreciated! Thanks. You got the bonus again:) Nobody remembers upvoting my question :P

Comment: Actually, I have now deleted the question posted back in 2013 (when I just registered an account on SE).. and it's still visible. Am I not getting something correctly? should it be visible?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: if you have a direct URL to the post you can always still view it if it is your own post or you have 10k+ reputation.